# Introduce inputs to a child process from R with python subprocess

Tags: python, r, subprocess

I have a parent process written in python calling for a child process in R with subprocess.call(), but I want to provide some of the variables I created in Python as inputs to the child process in R. My question is how do I introduce the inputs on the line subprocess.call() and in the R script of child process?

Also: using Windows

Variables in python parent process desired to be input for R

```
sg = 1  
vector_size = 100  
window = 10  
min_count = 1  
min_n = 0  
max_n = 0  
epochs = 2
```

Subprocess call for calling R child process

```
subprocess.call(r"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\Rscript", r"--vanilla foodChemSVDOutly.R", shell = True)
```

R script looks like this

```
sg = 1
vector_size = 100
window = 10
min_count = 1
min_n = 0
max_n = 0
epochs = 5

# Load data
model_id = sprintf('sg%s_vecsize%s_window%s_mincount%s_minn%s_maxn%s_epochs%s', sg, vector_size, window, min_count, min_n, max_n, epochs)
cos_sim_file_loc = sprintf('cossim_chems_%s.csv', model_id)
dat = fread(cos_sim_file_loc)

#Some statistical analyses here

#Writes output of analyses
outplier_file_loc = sprintf('outlier_chems_%s.csv', model_id)
fwrite(dat[nonOut == 0, ][order(z_risk, decreasing = TRUE)], outplier_file_loc)
```

So, I only need the inputs into R script, so that I can have the names of input and output .csv's automatically changed when variables change in
Python, instead of having to manually change them by myself.

I am aware of https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-subprocess/ which explains providing inputs from Python parent process to another Python child process.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does your R script look like? How does it expect the command line variables to be passed to it? How would you run it directly from the terminal?

Comment: edited my question to answer your question

Comment: There are myriad ways to achieve this. The most natural is to use an embedded R session with a package like [`rpy2`](https://rpy.sourceforge.io/). But if you want to go the hard way and start a subprocess, you are basically calling an Rscript from the commandprompt, and similar to doing this in Python you'll need to provide them as [commandline arguments](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/09/passing-arguments-to-an-r-script-from-command-lines/) to be used in R. There are many packages to handle this in R. embedding has added benefit that you'll be able to call the function **directly** in python

Comment: @Oliver thanks! I was able to indeed embed the little part into python, if you provide it as an answer, I will confirm it :)